# Cat6 utp cable installation at home

Tags: networking, router, linksys

I'm going to install cat6 utp cable in my house but, i want it in the same place where my electrical cable is installed (120 volts).

I was reading in other sites but some of them says that is recommended to separate both cables (ethernet and electrical). It is true or false??

Hope you can help me.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is true, but your actual experience/use may not show the issue.

As mains power is Alternating Current, cables carrying it give off Electromagnetic Interference.

If the EMI is strong enough, it can induce a current in the Cat6 cable, affecting the data being carried.

The Strength of the EMI is affected by how far the cables follow each other, what quality of mains cable is in use and if the Cat6 is shielded or unshielded, to name a few things.

You can reduce the effect by using a (more expensive) Shielded Cat6, rather than an unshielded one, or you can prevent it by running your cables so they don't follow your Mains power.

Comment: Ok Steven, i'll install my cat6  cable in other place, thanks for your answer!!

Comment: No worries, please be more mindful of where you post a question like this. As the note says, this would be more applicable in SuperUser. If you accept my answer, I'd be grateful for the green tick :)

Comment: I'm so sorry, but i didn't noticed that, btw, I already put this question as answered.